# Title with bottom border smaller than width

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to create an **underline effect** with a bottom border that is smaller than the `h2` title's width. Usually I don't upload images but I figure it might help explaining the question a bit further:

[image: Title with a bottom border smaller than is't width]

Comment: An h2 which has got relative position and an span which is absolute.

Comment: @scripter not working http://jsfiddle.net/MkgNG/1/

Answer (score 20):

You could use a pseudo-element for this. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ39x/)

```
.pseudo_border {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.pseudo_border:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    top:100%;
    margin:10px auto;
    width:50%;
    height:6px;
    background:#00f;
}
```

Just absolutely position a pseudo-element relative to the parent element. Position it `100%` from the `top` and use a combination of `left:0; right:0` and a `margin` of `auto` for horizontal centering. Modify the height/width of the element accordingly and change the `margin-top` for the spacing.

Comment: I would go with this solution

Answer (score 7):

### Other approach :

Box shadow with a negative spread radius :

```css
body{text-align:center;}
h2{
  font-size:40px;
  color:#409FB3;
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 0 -23px #5CC7A8;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some title</h2>
```

*Note : you need to make sure that `- spread-radius x2 < height` otherwise the box-shadow will have 0 height and disapear.*

Comment: Can the downvoter explain pls. I'm ok with that but without explanation it's pointless.

Comment: Except that there doesn't seem to be any way to modify the length of the shadow independently, only the thickness.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using `linear-gradient`. In this method, a small background image is created using gradients such that it is transparent for the first and last 25% while the rest 50% has the color (thus making it look like it is 50% of the actual `h2` text). This background is then positioned at the bottom of the element to make it look like a bottom border. The size of the border can be varied by modifying the background-size.

The effect would hold good even when the amount of text within the `h2` varies. The main drawback however is the relatively poor browser support for gradients as compared to the pseudo-element or the box-shadow approach.

<sup>Note: The use of the script in the answer is only for avoiding browser prefixes :)</sup>

```css
h2{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 15px; /* bottom padding should be higher to make up for pseudo border height */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 25%, lightseagreen 25%, lightseagreen 75%, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.semitransparent{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 25%, lightseagreen 25%, lightseagreen 75%, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0%, rgba(50,50,50,0.25) 0%);
  background-size: 100% 5px, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 100%, 0% -5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}

.colored{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 25%, lightseagreen 25%, lightseagreen 75%, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0%, aliceblue 0%);
  background-size: 100% 5px, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 100%, 0% -5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}

/* Just for demo */

body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<h2>Some Text</h2><br/>
<h2 class='semitransparent'>Some Lengthy Text</h2><br/>
<h2 class='colored'>Some more examples yay!!</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a sort of 'fake' border by simply wrapping a div around it and making a border div after the title

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J46Np/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="border-wrapper">
    <h2>My address</h2>
    <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#border-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#border{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the solutions I've seen for this effect in the past have relied on positioning - but using `display: flex` we can achieve it pretty easily. The below is an example of a heading, but it can be used on any element. Just bear in mind the nature of `flex-direction: column` will stack any child elements.

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="heading">Hey presto! We have an underline.</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Note you may have to add vendor prefixes for flex depending on browser support (mostly previous versions of IE, of course) https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 ::after {
   background: #f1991b none repeat scroll 0 0;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   height: 2px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   width: 50px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.main{
    text-align:center;
}
.title{
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.title::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff5533;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
 <div class="main">
    <h1 class="title">
        Your Title
    </h1>
</div>
```